Is the Bull queue in NestJS the best solution for this situation? (best practice)
I have a back-end built with NestJS and MongoDB, where I'm utilizing microservices to communicate with other services.
I have a POST endpoint that handles complex logic:
First, I retrieve data from two external APIs.
Then, I use two nested loops, each iterating through the data obtained from the external APIs in the previous step.
Within these nested loops, I fetch additional data from a third external API and send it to a microservice.
The microservice then persists the data in the database.
Instead of waiting for all these processes to complete before sending a response to the client, indicating success, I've implemented the Bull task queue in NestJS to handle these four steps asynchronously. The client receives a success response immediately, while Bull continues processing the data.
My question is whether this approach is suitable, or if there's a better alternative?"
// data.controller.ts
import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Queue } from 'bull';

@Controller('data')
export class DataController {
  constructor(@InjectQueue('data-queue') private readonly dataQueue: Queue) {}

  @Post('enqueue')
  async enqueueDataTasks(@Body() param) {
    await this.dataQueue.add(param);
    return 'success';
  }
}

// data.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  async fet`your text`chDataFromExternalAPI(): Promise<any[]> {
    // the complex steps that I mentioned before here
  }
}

// data-queue.processor.ts
import { Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Job } from 'bull';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Processor('data-queue')
export class DataQueueProcessor {
  constructor(private readonly dataService: DataService) {}

  @Process()
  async processJob(job: Job<any>) {
    await this.dataService.fetchDataFromExternalAPI();
  }
}


I think it's very depends on what exactly you're fetching and resources you are using. If you provide me with some more details i think i could help :)

i am now just mocking the data i created a service that generate a json file data that i will be consume , all things work fine using bull, but when i added a socket.io to the consumer class , i emit a message to client for each iteration on the reade of data using socket.io , sometimes the client can catch it sometimes not , if u have some suggestion or thought i will be glad to hear .
